# Check for Event Daily, and Send Notification Messages

Tags: php, python, google-app-engine

What is the best way to set up a system that checks for events daily and sends messages via email, Twitter, SMS, and possibly Facebook? Keep in mind, that I do not have access to a web server with root access (Using Rackspace Cloud). Would PHP have a solution for this? Would there be any drawbacks to using Google App Engine and Python?

Comment: why would you say you don't have root access on Rackspace?

Comment: There is an options to rent out private servers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Google App Engine with Python you could use "Cron" to schedule a task to automatically run each day.

GAE also allows you to send emails, just a little tip: make sure that you 'invite' the email address used to send mail to the application as an administrator so that you can programatically send emails etc.